# Javascript multi-nested Objects losing deeper-level Object's variables

Tags: javascript, object

I have what is basically an object that nests an object that nests a third.
What I have found is the last object's constructor information suddenly disappears.

Ex: A PlayerPos object that contains two Triangle objects, which each in turn contain three Point objects.

Here is what I have done to debug:

```
// Points to be used
var one = new Point(1, 2);
var two = new Point(2, 3);
var three = new Point(3, 4);

// Creation of the triangle
var tri = new Triangle(one, two, three);

// Check the console to see what it outputs.
console.log(tri);
```

At this point the console tells me this:

```
Triangle {front: Point, oneBack: Point, twoBack: Point}
```

Which, is exactly what I want. Everything is going well so far.

I then decided to make the PlayerPos.

```
// Create player position
var player = new PlayerPos(tri, tri);

// Check the log to make sure it can still find the triangles.
// (next) is one of PlayerPos's constructor names.
console.log(player.next);
```

This outputs:

```
Triangle {front: undefined, oneBack: undefined, twoBack: undefined}
```

Wait. What?

Why does the Triangle in PlayerPos suddenly decides to dump what it knows?  And how to fix this.

Comment: Show us the code for the `PlayerPos` constructor

Comment: It seems like you are missing the references to the nested instances which I assume is set in the constructor of `Triangle`? Without more implementation detail about how these points are set on the `Triangle` instance in the constructor there's not much to go on.

Comment: Opps. I was messing with things and put next = new Triangle();  My bad.